# CMD: Enter code

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like that the person who uses this batch file in the batch file must be enter the code "7570640".

If the code is right: A message appears saying "The code is correct."

If the code is wrong: A message appears saying "The code is wrong." then the CMD Window should close.

I´m a absolute noob (when creating batch files and in the english language. :P).

I hope someone can help me with my code. Thanks

```
@echo off

set /p var= Welcome in the HASH (H$) alpha program. [ENTER]

set /p var= Start the Code Generator and type in the code. [ENTER]

set /p pattern= Code: 

pause
```

Comment: check the [`IF`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_if_else_statement.htm) command. ;)

Comment: What would be the use case? A batch script is a plain text file, and anyone can open it in Notepad, and look for the code to enter. That completely defies protecting whatever you are trying to protect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `pause` in your script with this:

```
if "%pattern%" == "7570640" (echo The code is correct.) else (echo the code is wrong!)
pause
```

BTW I suggest you to remplace the first two `set` in your script by an `echo`
and also convert your .bat to an .exe so the user can't just right click>edit it and see your code:
http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php
EDIT
based on what SomethingDark said, you can use aes encryption/decription tool drom here: http://www.f2ko.de/en/cmd.php

Comment: Also, do **NOT** use batch-to-exe converters to conceal your code; the exe file just pastes the actual text in a temp directory that anyone can find. If you want something that people can't easily look up, either compare the _hash_ of the string like you would when you enter a password into a website, or use a language that _actually compiles_.

Comment: That AES tool is super sketchy. https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d1316c7ec77456b457505c773f053e8fc4bf1a623b7da93942ead5eb4a9d1451/analysis/1486431592/